# How to list a Category Blog and sub-categories with Articles still in Category Blog layout?

Tags: joomla-3.x, category-blog, subcategories

Using Joomla 3.8.5. Using the Menu Category Blog I've been able to list the Category title as a heading, and the Articles in blog layout style with two columns for the Articles using a Read More when needed.

I want to do the above with sub-categories but can't seem to figure this out.

This is what I want the desired output to look like:

Main Category Title
The description of the main category title's purpose goes here.

First Sub-Category Title

First title of the Article in this Sub-Category
Contents of the First Article in this Sub-Category

Second title of the Article in this Sub-Category
Contents of the Second Article in this Sub-Category

Second Sub-Category Title
First title of the Article in this Second Sub-Category
Contents of the First Article in this Second Sub-Category

I am using the *Articles - Category* module to list the above, but it only contains the links to the Articles. I want the Category Blog to apply to the Sub-Categories too.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a **nice looking main category page that has**:

- title and category description for parent category;
- title and list of articles from subcategory 1;
- title and list of articles from subcategory 2;
- etc.

**I can recommend a very flexible method** that I use. It provides many configuration options for your needs. It's implied that categories and subcategories and articles in them are already there on your site.

1. **Create a menu item (category blog) for your parent category**. 
   In the menu item parameters set to display only title and category   description. In Blog Layout tab, put zero for all article fields.
2. Take a [content module with wide functionality like RAXO All-mode PRO](https://www.raxo.org/raxo-all-mode-pro.html). Set the module to display articles from subcategory 1, and adjust all the other settings - thumbnail size, ordering by date or by popularity, etc.
   **Assign the module to this menu item** and place it in a appropriate module position.
3. **Make a copy of this module**. Go to its settings and change only one thing - show articles from subcategory 2.
4. Repeat step 3 as many times as you need to fill in the category page. 
   Here you can create module blocks like "popular in this category", "latest news", "most commented articles".